# Computing homology group of undirected bipartite graphs

Tags: algebraic-topology, graph-theory, homology-cohomology

Call homology group of a graph to be the homology group of the smallest genus surface on which the graph has an embedding. We know $K_{3,3}$ has genus $1$. That means its homology group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$. In general homology group of $K_{2n+2,2n+2}$ is $\Bbb Z^{n^2}$.

What is the right way to compute graph homology without using embedding into surface with homology group $\Bbb Z^{2g}$ where $g$ genus of given bipartite undirected graph (need not be complete)?

Comment: This is a nice question, but not of research level. I'm voting to move it to MSE.

Comment: @HJRW do you know how to compute invariant?

Comment: Actually, on reflection I don't know what you mean by "the homology group" of a graph. Usually one would mean the homology of the graph, thought of as a topological space.  For a connected graph, the only interesting group is $H_1$, and Euler characteristic tells us that it is $\mathbb{Z}^{1-V+E}$.  But you seem to mean the first homology group of the minimal genus surface into which the graph embeds. Is that correct? If so, I suggest you edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @HJRW yes that is why I posted on MO. It is not clear how to approach the problem. It is clear $K_{2n+2,2n+2}$ has $|V|=4n+4$ vertices and $|E|=(2n+2)^2$ edges. And $|E|-|V|+1=(2n+2)^2-(4n+4)+1=4n^2-1$ and graph genus almost never agrees with $|E|-|V|+1$.

Comment: But now the problem is precisely to compute the genus of the graph (since $H_1$ of a surface always has rank $2g$).  It's not an easy problem, but there's lots of literature on it.

Comment: @HJRW if the embedding is known it is easy. can we avoid the embedding step and do everything algebraically? I think this is fit for MO.

Comment: I don't think it can be done algebraically. It may be suitable for MO, but first you should look extensively at the literature. For instance, the wikipedia article points out that the problem of computing the genus is known to be NP-complete: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding .

Comment: @HJRW I know and NP completeness of the problem is well known and my purpose is not to find an efficient one but something that avoids embedding.